# How to work around `pywintypes.com_error` using pyrtd/pythoncom?

Tags: python, pywin32, win32com, rtd, pythoncom

I am trying to use the [pyrtd](https://code.google.com/p/pyrtd/) module for Python to get the information which can be got in Excel through RTD.

However, when I try to run the [sample python script](http://code.google.com/p/pyrtd/source/browse/examples/rtdtime.py), I get the following error:

```
pywintypes.com_error:( -2147221164, 'Class not registered', None, None)
```

I have tried several other RTD function and sometimes (When I am using `Dllname.function_name` as the parameter for `RTDClient()`) I get:

```
pywintypes.com_error:( -2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)
```

All of these RTD functions work well in Excel 2010.

I have not found a solution for Python yet, but I have gone through some of the tips available for C#:

- [A C# client for Excel real-time data (RTD) servers](https://andrewsheppard.wordpress.com/2010/10/23/a-real-time-data-rtd-server-written-in-c/)
- [Excel RTD Client in C#](http://awkwardcoder.com/2014/01/24/excel-rtd-client-in-c/)
- http://bbs.csdn.net/topics/320252117
- [Excel RTD Servers: Multiple Topics in C#](http://blog.lab49.com/archives/2684)

#### The basic idea is:

1. Get the class type of rtd server from register table by `ProgID` (for example, `RTDTime.RTD`, you can find them in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\RTDTime.RTD`, if you have already used *regsvr32* to register the dll).

   In C#, the function is `Type.GetTypeFromProgID()`. **I believe there is a same function in Python module `win32com`**.
2. Cast the server class to `IRtdServer` (`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.IRtdServer`).
3. Then one can use `IRtdServer.ConnectData(topicID, topics, newData)` to get the data:

   - `topicID` seems to be any random `int`;
   - `topics` is the parameters you used in Excel, it is an array;
   - `newData` is a `bool`, set it to be `True` if you request new data and not the cached data.
4. However, I believe if one wants to get the data updated automatically, one would need a callback event.

According to [the linked blog post](https://andrewsheppard.wordpress.com/2010/10/23/a-real-time-data-rtd-server-written-in-c/), the event class can also be got by `progID`. **But I have not found any in the reg table**.

**In C# I think it maybe possible to create a `IRTDUpdateEvent`. But I don't know how to deal with it with Python.**

Could someone help me work around these errors?

Answer (score 2):

Solved. Install and use 32-bit ActivePython

http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/Problem-using-win32com-client-Dispatch-on-Win7-64bit-td1957248.html

It may because I am using 64-bit python and trying to get 32-bit com object

Answer (score 0):

P.S.

pyrtd module only support single topic subscription.

User needs to do little modification on pyrtd.py to pass a tuple to enable multiple topic sub:

Line116

```
self._rtd.ConnectData(id, list(topic), True)
```