# Base64 Docx to Base64 pdf

Tags: python, django, base64, django-staticfiles, docx2pdf

Im trying to convert a Base64 Docx to a Base64 pdf, for test purpose im receiving the base64 docx and im saving it in my Django static folder like this:

```
Proyect
--App
----static
------Docs
--------test.docx
```

So, Im trying with doxc2pdf library to make the convertion and the into base64 like this:

```
class Converttest(View):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        template = loader.get_template('home.html')

        testdoc = static('Docs/test.docx')
        pdf = convert(testdoc)
        encoded = base64.b64encode(pdf)
        context = {}
        return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

But im getting this error:

```
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)
> g:\python_projects\reps\stratos\strategy\views.py(162)post()
-> convert(testdoc)
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25181932/how-to-work-around-pywintypes-com-error-using-pyrtd-pythoncom

Comment: Thanks for your answer but no, tried too and same error

Answer (score 0):

```
sample_string = "test string"
sample_string_bytes = sample_string.encode("ascii")
  
base64_bytes = base64.b64encode(sample_string_bytes)
base64_string = base64_bytes.decode("ascii")
```